# Can you add an existing customer payment method to an existing sales order through Acumatica API?

Tags: acumatica

I have created a Customer Payment Method through the API using the AR301000 screen.  However, I have run into an error when trying to add the payment method to a sales order.  Here is my current code.

```
    SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
    context.SO301000Clear();
    SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit
    (
        new Command[]
            {
                //add header info
                new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },
                new Value { Value = "000129", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },
                //add payment
                new Value { Value = "VISA", LinkedCommand = SO301000.PaymentSettings.PaymentMethod },
                new Value { Value = "VISA:****-****-****-7261", LinkedCommand = SO301000.PaymentSettings.CardAccountNo },

                SO301000.Actions.Save
            }
    );
```

When trying to run, it gives the following error:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXException: Error #12: Updating  'Sales Order' record raised one or more errors. Please review. Error: 'Card/Account No' may not be empty.

Is there another Card/Account number field that must be updated?

Answer (score 0):

```
    You have to use different approach

    SO301000Content orderSchema = context.SO301000GetSchema();
    var commands = new Command[]
    {
        new Value 
        {
            Value = orderType, 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType 
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = orderNbr, 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr 
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = "TOKENCC", 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettings.PaymentMethod 
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = "True", 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettings.NewCard 
        },
new Value { Value = "VISA", LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettings.PaymentMethod },

//below you have to fill attributes (pairs key-value)
        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.ObjectName,
            FieldName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.FieldName,
            Value = "='CCDNUM'"
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = "4321111111111234", 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Value 
        },

        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.ObjectName,
            FieldName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.FieldName,
            Value = "='CVV'"
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = "321", 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Value 
        },


        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.ObjectName,
            FieldName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.FieldName,
            Value = "='EXPDATE'"
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = "01/2019", 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Value 
        },

        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.ObjectName,
            FieldName = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Description.FieldName,
            Value = "='NAMEONCC'"
        },
        new Value 
        {
            Value = "01/2019", 
            LinkedCommand = orderSchema.PaymentSettingsCardInfoDescription.Value 
        },

        orderSchema.Actions.Save
    };
```

Comment: The account/card number I'm actually entering above is a token that is associated with an Authorize.net payment profile which should allow me to authorize/charge card from within Acumatica.  It looks like the code suggestion above actually puts the new card info (ie: card number, exp date, etc.) into Acumatica.  Is that correct?